# Is a golf ball still more aerodynamic than a normal sphere in turbulent flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

[image: Does this still apply]

If I have turbulent flow (Reynolds number of 10^6) would this principle still apply?

Comment: That is what golfers pay extra for. Allegedly long ago the effect was first noticed by a Scottish golfer who was was repeatedly reusing his initially smooth golf balls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the [dimples](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-dimples-in-golf-ba/) is to create a thin boundary layer of turbulent air that clings to the surface of the golf ball.  This allows the laminar flow of air around the ball to travel farther down the back side of the ball, creating a thinner wake, which means less drag on the ball.

If the ball travels through turbulent air, the dimples still allow the ball to create a thinner wake, and it will travel farther than a smooth ball, though it will travel neither as straight nor as far as it would through laminar air.